# How to add OpenStreetMap as background layer to my sharpmap map

Tags: c#, asp.net, gis, openstreetmap, sharpmap

I have a web application which uses sharpmap 1.1 to generate maps(Works Pretty awesome), now i want to add an Open street map as background to my current map. I tried some online examples but no luck.

So far I've tried the below.

```
   var ShapeDataProvider = new SharpMap.Data.Providers.ShapeFile(@"Local shp Path");
        var layer = new VectorLayer("test");
        layer.DataSource = ShapeDataProvider;
      var layerOSM = var layer = new VectorLayer("OSM");
layerOSM.DataSource = (SharpMap.Data.Providers.IProvider)(new SharpMap.Layers.TileAsyncLayer(new BruTile.Web.OsmTileSource(), "OSM"));
        _map.Layers.Add(layerOSM);
        _map.Layers.Add(layer);
```

So far I'm stuck at this error and Literally no way pass this it seems,

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'BruTile.Web.OsmTileSource' to
>   'BruTile.ITileSource'

The version of assemblies I'm using in my project are

```
Sharpmap    1.1.0.0
 Brutile     0.7.4.4
 ProjNet     1.3.0.3
 NetTopologySuite  1.13.2.0
 GeoAPI   1.7.2.0
```

I've added all are from Nuget, If someone could share me a piece of code which works in accessing OpenStreetMap as background layer? 
that'll be a life-saver.

Thanks in advance, Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect different versions of the BruTile assembly referenced in your projects.

Comment: pauldendulk - Thanks for giving me an idea which resulted in the solution. I'm marking your answer as correct as it was indeed a issue of different assembly referenced in my project. I removed all the references and added again from scratch from nuget.. works like a charm now... Cheers!